# NullPointerException on jetty 7 startup with jetty deployment descriptor

Tags: jetty

I'm getting the following error when I start Jetty:

```
2010-03-01 12:30:19.328:WARN::Failed startup of context WebAppContext@15ddf5@15ddf5/webapp,null,/path/to/jetty-distribution-7.0.1.v20091125/webapps-plus/webapp.war
```

With this commandline:

```
java -jar start.jar OPTIONS=All lib=/path/to/jetty-distribution-7.0.1.v20091125/lib/ext etc/jetty.xml etc/jetty-plus.xml /path/to/webapp/src/configuration/test.xml
```

And test.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Mort Bay Consulting//DTD Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/webapp</Set>
  <Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps-plus/webapp.war</Set>
</Configure>
```

If I don't include test.xml on the commandline it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

my guess is, you have an additional slash. replace

```
<Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/webapps-plus/webapp.war</Set>
```

with

```
<Set name="war"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default=".">/webapps-plus/webapp.war</Set>
```

Comment: That's not properly formed XML.

Comment: sorry. thought it belonged to the `Set` tag.